# Sql command change connection only

Tags: vb.net

Is there any way to change only the connection on an SQL command?

I want to execute the same command on two databases (my main and backup databases).

Something along these lines:

```
Cmd.connection = dbMain
Cmd.executenonquery 
Cmd.connection = dbbackup
Cmd.executenonquery`
```

Code snippet:

```
Using _cmdInsert
      _cmdInsert.ExecuteNonQuery()
End Using

Try
   Dim _conR As New SqlConnection
   _conR.ConnectionString = Replace(_connectionstring, "_MAIN_", "_BACKUP_")
   _conR.Open()

   cmdInsert.Connection = conR

        Using _cmdInsert
              _cmdInsert.ExecuteNonQuery()
        End Using

    _conR.Close()
 Catch ex As Exception

 End Try
```

Comment: What happens when you try?

Comment: It says violation of primary key because my key is not AI. Assuming by that error im sure that connection is not changed. When i debug thgrough breakpoints everything was fine with connections, but somehow it does not change it

Comment: Don't assume, debug.  Can you profile the databases in question and observe the queries being sent to them?  That would confirm which database is receiving the second query.

Comment: I dont understand that part ?? Before execution when i look the details everything was fine, data, connection, parameters but everything. I wonder do i miss something like cmd.prepare or smth similar

Comment: What is the command you're trying to execute on both DBs?

Comment: Its long sqlcommand using the sql parameters with a lot of conditions for creating them. Lets say im using one query ? Update table01 set id=id. How would that go ? If necessary i can put entire code

Comment: What database is it?  Some support attached tables that you would not have change the connection - you could act like they are both members of the same db.  Acting on a backup seems...odd

Comment: Actually im trying to insert through the view of table in another database. In backup database i have a view ..

Comment: Just hit edit. Please take a review

Comment: So this insert command is failing for primary key violation when run within your VB code but succeeds if run via SSMS?

Comment: It works great. If i type update in sqlcommand insted of insert it will only change record in main database

Comment: So inserting works in both but updating doesn't? And you're certain the key being used for the update is identical in both databases?

Answer (score 1):

```
Cmd.connection = dbMain
using(cmd)
{

   Cmd.executenonquery ;

}

  Cmd.connection = dbbackup;
 using (cmd)
 {

   Cmd.executenonquery;
 }
```

Comment: what is query and are you generating pk automatically or not, its the issu with that I think

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in that for both database was used the same sql server.

And query was smth like Update database.dbo.table  assuming the table was same and databases was on same sql server no matter how many times i oppen sql connection it still update the same databse.